# Она, что, крикнула: «Ты что там наделал?!»(?)

Tags: прямая-речь

Понятно, что здесь съедается вопросительный знак главного предложения.

> Она, что, спросила только: «Как у тебя дела?»

А здесь?

> Она, что, крикнула: «Ты что там наделал?!»(?)

А здесь восклицательный съедается?

> Я ненавижу её, после того как она крикнула: «Ты дебил, что ли-с?!»(!)

Comment: Леопольд, перед _что_ не ставится запятая.

Comment: Но здесь значение *что ли*!

Comment: Тогда ладно, пусть так будет.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, «съедаются»:

***Она, что, крикнула: «Ты что там наделал?!»***

***Я ненавижу её, после того как она крикнула: «Ты дебил, что ли-с?!»***

Можно проверить себя, заменив прямую речь курсивом:

«Она, что, крикнула: *Ты что там наделал?!*?»

«Я ненавижу её, после того как она крикнула: *Ты дебил, что ли-с?!*!»

Так себе, правда? Поэтому, я считаю, дополнительные знаки **не нужны**.